# access useState variable in cleanup/return method of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I have a field like so

```js
const SimpleReactComponent = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('DEFAULT')

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // unmount 
      console.log(`[${title}] while unmounting`)
    }
  }, [])
  return <TextInput value={title} onChangeText={title => setTitle(title)}></TextInput>
}
```

When I modify the `title` field and navigate away from this component, it still prints the following

```sh
[DEFAULT] while unmounting
```

While I'm expecting the newly modified value instead of `DEFAULT`.

How to capture the changes while component is unmounting?

Comment: Please research more about Hooks dependencies. It seems to me that is the issue.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: Add `title` into your dependency for that hook. That should tell React to run this `useEffect` when `title` changes

Comment: It shows intial value because of "stale closure". Related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66435915/2873538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the title value in the dependency array of the hook. If not the hook will only run when the component mounts and will log the initial value in that time.
Adding the **title** in the dependency array will make the useEffect listen everytime the **title** value changes and it will display the correct value when you unmount the component.

```
const SimpleReactComponent = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('DEFAULT')

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // unmount 
      console.log(`[${title}] while unmounting`)
    }
  }, [title])
  // Dependency array need the title to run everytime the value changes and when the unmount runs it will have the latest value!

  return <TextInput value={title} onChangeText={title => setTitle(title)}></TextInput>
}
```

Comment: But when title changes, the console.log would prompt the old value, wouldn't it? How to access the new title inside the cleanup function?

Comment: Indeed @MarioEis, it will prompt the old value. To get the most recent value, create a ref: `const titleRef = useRef()` followed by `titleRef.current = title`, outside of the effect (e.g. next to useState in the example) and then access the value in the cleanup function `console.log(titleRef.current)`.