# useSelector returns initial state in one page and correct state in other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, web-frontend

I have the following situation: In component `<Home />` I have a component made my me, `<AutocompleteSearch />` which displays a list of books, and when we click one book, it does an api call to fetch the details about clicked book then and dispatch that saves in the books state, the current book. My problem is that I have an listener in the `<Home />` component that when is triggered it checks if some value is equal with the current book id, and for that I use **useSelector** to get the current book in the `<Home />`, but I get an error saying that currentBook is undefined, I printed the books state and it prints an empty object that is the initial state. The strange thing is that I have another component in my `<Home />`, called  to which I pass as props the current book, and in `BookProfile` the current book prop is a fine object, fetched from server, so the state updates correct, but when I try to access the current book in the `<Home />` it look like it never changed, and as well I wanna say, I tried to use the same useSelector in another child component of home, and it works here too, it logs in console a fine object from server, representing the last clicked book in the `AutocompleteSearch`.

I'll insert some code snippets:

```
      const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.users.currentUser)
      const currentBook = useSelector(state => state.book.currentBook)
      
      return (
       ...........
       {openSearchBar && (
          <AutoCompleteSearch
            suggestionsList={bookListForSearchBar}
            elementClickAction={setMainContent}
          />
        )}
       ...........
       <BookProfile
            book={currentBook}
            user={currentUser}
          />
...
}

  const bookListClicked = async book=> {
    await dispatch(getCurrentBook(book.id))
  }
const currentBookReceived = book=> ({
  type: actions.CURRENT_BOOK_RECEIVED,
  anime,
})

export default function News() {
  const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.users.currentUser)
  const currentBook = useSelector(state => state.book.currentBook)

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(currentUser)
          console.log(currentBook)
        }}>
        News
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

In `News` components state works fine, it logs the correct book, but in `Home` it logs undefined.

```
let initialState={}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.CURRENT_BOOK_RECEIVED:
      return { ...state, currentBook: action.book }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Also, currentUser is fetched from server after succes at login then saved in users state with dispatch, and I printed it in console in Home and it is as it should be, not undefined like currentBook.

I am new in front-end development and I don't understand very well how the things works, I don't understand why in one component the state is seen well and in another it is not.

Comment: Are you saying that the selector `const currentBook = useSelector(state => state.book.currentBook)`, in `News` component, selects the latest data from Redux store, but it doesn't do the same in `Home` component? If yes, that sounds unusual. We can surely help you fix this if you can create a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces this issue, preferably in a https://codesandbox.io.

Comment: @AjeetShah I will try to create that minimal code example,in the meantime I tried some more debug,I put an onClick event listener on some div I have in `Home` and this listener calls a function that logs to console the `currentBook` and it works,it logs the correct book from state,but where I try to use it is here: `function con() {var s=new SockJS('ip')
var a= Stomp.over(s)
a.connect({}, function (frame) {
a.subscribe('/p', function (c) {
const commentResponse = JSON.parse(c.body) console.log(currentBook)
})})}`,here currentBook is null, as in initialState, but currentUser is fine here.

Comment: Seems like it is [stale closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66435915/2873538) issue.